# What's this type of content actually called?

Tags: 7, theming

I think I've been getting the terminology wrong.

When I open a Panel and go to the Content region and click the gear icon, then Add Content a modal appears.

On the left of this modal are categories housing various site components - gallerys, forms, HTML, etc

What are these things collectively actually called?

Answer (score 0):

I think those are called site content (but I don't know if you'll find a name for all of them written somewhere, as you said).